# The method getCount is undefined for type LinkedList

Tags: java, list, data-structures

I am trying to get the count of list. I wrote separate function to get the count. When I am calling this into the main, It is throwing error.
error is

> getCount is undefined for type LinkedList.

My code is

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.LinkedList.*;
public class LengthCount {
Node head;
// Insert a new node from the front.
public void push(int new_data){
    Node new_node = new Node(new_data);
    new_node.next = head;
    head = new_node;
}
// Function for getting count
public int getCount(){
    int count = 0;
    Node temp = head;
    while(temp != null){
        count++;
        temp = temp.next;
    }
    return count;
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    LinkedList llist = new LinkedList();
    llist.push(1);
    llist.push(3);
    llist.push(1);
    llist.push(2);
    llist.push(1);
    System.out.println("Counts of node is : "+llist.getCount()); // Error in this line

}

}
```

Can any body please help me

Comment: You defined that method in your LengthCount class. Why do you expect it to be present in java.util.LinkedList?

Comment: LinkedList has no member function getCount() ([API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html)).

Comment: getcount is user define function. Can we call user define function with list or not ? Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you trying to get the length of list. Then use API.  Here is your modified code

```
import java.util.*;


public class LengthCount {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LinkedList llist = new LinkedList();
        llist.push(1);
        llist.push(3);
        llist.push(1);
        llist.push(2);
        llist.push(1);
        System.out.println("Counts of node is : "+llist.size());

    }}
```

Answer (score 2):

GetCount is a method defined in the class  **LengthCount**  . So you have to either create an object of the class to access the method or Use *this.getCount()*.

You can not use *List.getCount()* as Linked list class does not have that method instead , It has List.size();

Comment: Then there is no need to write different function to for push and get count. We can directly use from API right ?

Comment: Yes ,The API methods yields  optimum results . Also If at all you have to change any implementation you inherit the base list class and overrides its functions.

Comment: thanks Sthya. This will help more to understand linkedlist